# VM not working after Reset

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, reset

Our VM is no longer resolving since we did a reset.
Reserved IP address is no longer assigned, we can not find a way to re-assign.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Pablo

Comment: What Hypervisor? What is providing the IP?

Comment: Google is providing IP

Comment: Hypervisor is provided by Google cloud as well

Comment: Have you tried stopping the vm and then editing its network interfaces settings?

Comment: Yes, we even created a new VM from snapshot using previous IP and URL still not resolving... any ideas?

Comment: Our ports seem closed... where can we fix this in google cloud?

Comment: Nmap scan report for open2europe.com (35.240.21.94)
rDNS record for 35.240.21.94: 94.21.240.35.bc.googleusercontent.com
PORT STATE SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http
443/tcp filtered https

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have reserved an [Static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#reservenewip).

There are two ways you can assign a reserved IP address. First upon creating a VM instance there is an option where you can click “Advance Option” look on “External IPv4 address then click drop down arrow then choose the reserved IP address created.

Another way is by going to VPC network > IP Address then from the created reserved IP address click “Change” then attach it to the VM instance that is already created.

Make sure that the reserved IP address have the same region with the VM instance created or going to create.